# how to hide and show add and remove material icon in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material, materialize

I have used 2 material icon (add and remove) to add or remove some items in md-list-items. My objective is to hide add icon and show remove icon if user clicks on add. OR if user clicks on remove then add icon will come instead of remove icon. both on click

```
  <i class="material-icons md-avatar-icon add-rm-icon margin-right">add</i>

  <i class="material-icons md-avatar-icon add-rm-icon margin-right">remove</i>
```

Comment: working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2qzno7jw/

Comment: create a boolean scope variable e.g `isAdd`; negate that everytime you click on one of the buttons

Comment: @Azola Thanks for suggestion. I'm new to angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way of doing it.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.add= false;
});
```

```css
/* Rules for sizing the icon. */
.material-icons.md-18 { font-size: 18px; }
.material-icons.md-24 { font-size: 24px; }
.material-icons.md-36 { font-size: 36px; }
.material-icons.md-48 { font-size: 48px; }

/* Rules for using icons as black on a light background. */
.material-icons.md-dark { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54); }
.material-icons.md-dark.md-inactive { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26); }

/* Rules for using icons as white on a dark background. */
.material-icons.md-light { color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); }
.material-icons.md-light.md-inactive { color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="added = true" ng-show="!added"><i class="material-icons">add</i> Add</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="added = false" ng-show="added"><i class="material-icons">remove</i> Remove</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      Current State: {{added ? 'Added' : 'Not Added'}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `scope` variable to to show and hide the add and remove button.

Here is the code.

HTML Code

```
<div ng-controller="TempController">
 <md-button  ng-click="toggle = !toggle" class='md-primary md-raised'> Click Me!!  </md-button>
 <md-icon ng-if='toggle'>add</md-icon>
 <md-icon ng-if='!toggle'>remove</md-icon>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngMaterial'])
.controller('TempController', function( $scope){
  $scope.toggle = false;
});
```

Working [Codepen](http://codepen.io/next1/pen/ggyNbW).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using angular, the simplest way would be to use either `ng-if` of `ng-show` or `ng-hide`

`ng-if` will actually render/derender the buttons, while the other two will simply show and hide them using css.  Then all you have to do is set them to a value in your controller.

```html
<i ng-if="$ctrl.add" ng-click="$ctrl.add= !$ctrl.add"> Add </i>
<i ng-if="!$ctrl.add" ng-click="$ctrl.add= !$ctrl.add"> Remove </i>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is easier:

```
<md-button class="material-icons md-avatar-icon add-rm-icon margin-right">
  <md-icon ng-click="add=!add">{{(add== true) ? 'add' : 'remove'}}</md-icon>
</md-button>
```